# UCWA 'Offline' status - invalid

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa

I trying to update my status to Offline (Skype for Business) , by POSTing

```
{"availability":"Offline"}
```

to `me/presence` url.

The response is: 400  Bad request

```
<code>BadRequest</code>
    <subcode>ParameterValidationFailure</subcode>
    <message>Please check what you entered and try again.</message>
    <debugInfo />
    <parameters>
        <property name="availability">Invalid</property>
    </parameters>
```

Same happens  with 'Away' status,
but statuses like 'Online', 'Busy' work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change your status to offline, the only solution I know about would be to issue a **DELETE** request to the [application URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/application_ref) specific to that UCWA session.  There really isn't an offline-mode for UCWA.  The enumeration for [Availability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/availability_ref) includes all the statuses, but sadly not an accurate description of what can/cannot be set via UCWA.

You should be able to set the following statuses:

- Away
- BeRightBack
- Busy
- DoNotDisturb
- Online

Offline (as stated above) is set as a result of the application no longer existing.

IdleBusy/IdleOnline are states that the server will set when the inactivity timer is trigger in the Busy/Online states.

Comment: It seems to take a long time for the UCWA application to change from being "Online" to being "Offline" after DELETE'ing the application through the REST api for some reason.  Compare with UCMA, where this change happens almost instantaneously.

Comment: I'm not certain why Away would not be working in your situation.  Are you able to set Away status from the desktop client?  The delay between Online --> Offline is dependent on how quickly the server can process the cleanup of the active UCWA application which may include destroying active conversations, subscriptions, and related resources.